# Angular JS and validation step by step

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I have an angular js wizard with steps:

```
<wizard on-before-step-change="log(event)" on-step-changing="log(event)" on-after-step-change="log(event)" user="user">

<step title="step 1">

</step>

<step title="step 2">

</step>

<step title="step 3">

</step>

</wizard>
```

and in each of these steps there are input fields and I am looking to validate each step at a time when they click my next button:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="gotoNextStep()" ng-show="showNextButton()">Next</a>
```

and here is the click event:

```
$scope.gotoNextStep = function () {
          //Validation
          toggleSteps($scope.currentStepIndex + 1);
      }
```

I was looking to use jQuery validation and have the required class in each of my input fields, but if I went down that road how would I have it validate one step at a time?  Or is there a better way to go about this? I have did some searching on the subject, but I found the examples I found very confusing and complicated...any help would be much appreciated.

THanks.

Comment: Does each step have it's own button?

Comment: no they do not, this button is used for all steps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular provides a framework for validating forms ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)) and you can verify based upon `$valid` (or `$invalid`) for each step.

Also note that you can have one parent form, with each step utilizing the `ng-form` directive to work as a nested form.

I would add the following:

```
<wizard>
  <step> <!-- step 1 -->
    <div ng-form="step1" name="step1">
      <button ng-disabled="step1.$invalid">Next Step</button>
    </div>
  </step>
</wizard>
```

If you need to define a new validation, you can follow [this excellent article](http://www.benlesh.com/2012/12/angular-js-custom-validation-via.html)

Comment: so I would add ng-form to each of my steps and then what do I do with $valid or $invalid....can u provide an example?

Comment: your example is great, but I am looking to do the validation in the $scope.gotoNextStep function...is that possible?

Comment: You can use: `<button ng-click="gotoNextStep(1 /*step #*/, step1.$invalid)">...` to get the validity into your `$scope`

Comment: Will that work? I am reusing the same button for each step to goto the next step.

Comment: You can make the params dynamic `gotoNextStep(stepNumber)` and then reference the form dynamically in your controller... see this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/w4fbqsOHIxNGJFh18FOT?p=preview

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks!